# Kivy segmentation fault in Bionic with Hello World

Tags: python, ubuntu, kivy, ubuntu-18.04

New Kivy user here...

I'm having an issue with Kivy running in Bionic Ubuntu.  Simple Hello World application throws a segmentation fault.  The window pops on the screen of the device with a partial draw: frame and titlebar but with no background and immediately disappears with a segmentation fault in the kivy console output.

**My installation is:**

- Python: 2.7
- OS: Ubuntu - Linux bionic-xfce 4.9.88-5-boundary-14b
- Kivy: 1.10.1
- Kivy installation method: sudo apt-get install python-kivy from ppa:kivy-team/kivy
- Platform: Nitrogen6x Quad-2Gb from Boundary

**Python:**

```
import os
print(os.path)
from kivy.app import App

class MyApp(App):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

I initially had an issue with "Unable to find any valuable Window provider".  I had to add several of the required packages that did not load (mostly **libsdl** related), then ran glxinfo and used the last id (0x16a) to update the **environment:**

```
export SDL_VIDEO_X11_VISUALID=0x16a
```

This moved me past the "no valuable Window" errors, but still no joy.  Now it seg faults.

My **Kivy log shows:**

```
<module 'posixpath' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/posixpath.pyc'>
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /home/ubuntu/.kivy/logs/kivy_18-08-06_12.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.10.1
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v2.7.15rc1 (default, Apr 15 2018, 21:51:34)
[GCC 7.3.0]
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 194 symbols loaded
[DEBUG  ] [Cache       ] register <kv.lang> with limit=None, timeout=None
[DEBUG  ] [Cache       ] register <kv.image> with limit=None, timeout=60
[DEBUG  ] [Cache       ] register <kv.atlas> with limit=None, timeout=None
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_gif (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[DEBUG  ] [Cache       ] register <kv.texture> with limit=1000, timeout=60
[DEBUG  ] [Cache       ] register <kv.shader> with limit=1000, timeout=3600
[DEBUG  ] [App         ] Loading kv <./my.kv>
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[DEBUG  ] [Window      ] Ignored <egl_rpi> (import error)
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2(['window_egl_rpi'] ignored)
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glShaderBinary is not available
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <gl>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <2.1 V6.2.2.93313>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <Vivante Corporation>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <Vivante GC2000>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 2, 1
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <2.1.0 >
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <8192>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <8>
[DEBUG  ] [Shader      ] Fragment compiled successfully
[DEBUG  ] [Shader      ] Vertex compiled successfully
[DEBUG  ] [ImageSDL2   ] Load </usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/data/glsl/default.png>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[DEBUG  ] [Resource    ] add </usr/share/fonts> in path list
[DEBUG  ] [Resource    ] add </usr/share/fonts/truetype> in path list
[DEBUG  ] [Resource    ] add </usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu> in path list
[DEBUG  ] [Resource    ] add </usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu> in path list
[DEBUG  ] [Resource    ] add </usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont> in path list
[DEBUG  ] [Resource    ] add </usr/share/fonts/truetype/noto> in path list
[DEBUG  ] [Resource    ] add </usr/share/fonts/cMap> in path list
[DEBUG  ] [Resource    ] add </usr/share/fonts/X11> in path list
[DEBUG  ] [Resource    ] add </usr/share/fonts/X11/misc> in path list
[DEBUG  ] [Resource    ] add </usr/share/fonts/X11/util> in path list
[DEBUG  ] [Resource    ] add </usr/share/fonts/X11/encodings> in path list
[DEBUG  ] [Resource    ] add </usr/share/fonts/X11/encodings/large> in path list
[DEBUG  ] [Resource    ] add </usr/share/fonts/cmap> in path list
[DEBUG  ] [Resource    ] add </usr/local/share/fonts> in path list
[DEBUG  ] [Resource    ] add </usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/data/fonts> in path list
[DEBUG  ] [Base        ] Create provider from mouse
[DEBUG  ] [Base        ] Create provider from probesysfs
[DEBUG  ] [ProbeSysfs  ] using probesysfs!
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
[INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
[DEBUG  ] [Atlas       ] Load </usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/data/images/defaulttheme.atlas>
[DEBUG  ] [Atlas       ] Need to load 1 images
[DEBUG  ] [Atlas       ] Load </usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/data/images/defaulttheme-0.png>
[DEBUG  ] [ImageSDL2   ] Load </usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/data/images/defaulttheme-0.png>
Segmentation fault
```

Q: what should I look for next?  Is there any additional information I can provide that might help someone point me in the right direction?  Seems like I'm really close but thinking it's a GL or sdl issue since I had to load packages that didn't seem to come in the distribution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I ran your App using Kivy nightly build without problem. Try install Kivy nightly builds, `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kivy-team/kivy-daily`

Comment: unfortunately, that didn't help.  I've started over multiple times starting with a fresh image and still no luck.  I even changed to an even more basic `code`

Comment: `from kivy.app import App
App().run()`

Comment: I am having a similar issue on one of my Ubuntu 18.04 systems. I get a core dump after  the window flashes up. I have tried installing nightly, stable, building dev from scratch, building master , using various versions of Cython. There are no useful error messages other than core dump. However on my laptop with 18.04 nightly works fine. I'm starting to think this is a video driver issue with 18.04. I suppose I'll need to delve into the core dump and see exactly where this is crashing :( If anyone has any further ideas please let us know.

Comment: Ok I confirmed this is a video driver issue. I stuck in an nvidia card using the nouveau drivers and associated GL drivers and no other changes and it no longer core dumps and it works fine. So the built-in video (probably intel) is at fault or the drivers for it on 18.04. SO for me the problem is solved as I do not need to use the builtin video for this machine.